# snapping a puzzle piece to a hi view tile

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I'm making a puzzle game and am stuck on the logic of "snapping" my puzzle pieces (UIImageVIew) to a tile board(Subview of the main UIView). I have the game where I can drag each puzzle piece around from the main view but when it comes time for me place it in the correct tile square I don't know how to have it snap to the correct tile.

I read about using the centers as a way to determine where my puzzle piece is in the view but how can I determine how close it is to its "correct tile" and have it snap into its location.

Thanks for any future responses.

Comment: Hi! Please share some code to show what you've tried and ask a specific question where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between the `center` of the puzzle piece and the point where the center is supposed to be. You must have this information, otherwise you would not know when the puzzle piece is in the correct position.

You calculate the distance between two points like this:

```
CGPoint p = piece.center;
CGPoint b = correctPositionForPiece;

double distance = sqrtf( (p.x-b.x)*(p.x-b.x) + (p.y-b.y)*(p.y-b.y) );
```

Compare the distance to your required maximum distance on finger-up. Then animate the change with simple `UIView` animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
   piece.center = b;
}];
```